# Get ViewChild from base component in nesten component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I have three pretty similar custom dropdown components:

1. base-dropdown
2. dropdown-with-search
3. dropdown-with-search-advanced

They have many common behavior, but also they have some different. I decided to split them into three different component, because when it was one big component with 20 `@Input()` properties and many `if else` for choosing one or other behavior it was terrible. Also they have identical dropdown options. So the only difference is input(header, idk how to call it right) and button-press handlers.
Here is simplified [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bntcxw?file=app%2Fbase-dropdown.ts)

So here i have `setDropdownPosition()` method in `base-dropdown` component. It calculates where dropdown should be opened - above or below the input. In `dropdown-witch-search` component i ahve access to parent method, like `toggleOptions()` or `setDropdownPosition()`. But i don't have access to parent   `@ViewChild('dropdownContainer') dropdownContainer: ElementRef;` to position him in extended component. And `setDropdownPosition()` throw an error. Earlier i have own template in every component(and it works), but there were many repeatable things in every template, like i mentioned before - options and etc.
What is the best way to solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: what is the actual expectation you are looking for?

Comment: As i described in the question, i want to have  different dropdown components. Base-dropdown - nothing special - it works as it is now. But for `dropdown-witch-search` i want to have functionality of base-dropdown and something more that i will put as content inside `<base-dropdown>`. Right now in `dropdown-witch-search` i don't have access for `@ViewChild('dropdownContainer') dropdownContainer` and i can't choose where to display component

Comment: have all the logic in a single component and use a `input` to differentiate between them.

Comment: Did you read the question? I wrote: " I decided to split them into three different component, because when it was one big component with 20 @Input() properties and many if else for choosing one or other behavior it was terrible" and you suggest put all in one...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, so I'll explain the two ways :

1. Get a child variable from a parent component

   ```
   @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent; // One child
   @ViewChildren(ChildComponent) children: QueryList<ChildComponent>; // Several children

   ngOnInit() {
     this.child.someVariable = 'foo';
   }
   ```
2. Get a parent from the child

**Injector**

```
constructor(private injector: Injector){
  let parentComponent = this.injector.get(ParentComponent);
}
```

**Through input**

*parent*

```
parent = this;
```

*child*

```
@Input() parent: ParentComponent;
...
<app-child [parent]="parent"></app-child>
```

**Direct injection**

```
constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => ParentComponent)) private parent:ParentComponent) {}
```

Comment: Thank you for fast reply. I have already saw this answers on stackoverflow, but it is not what i need. It seems it is not possible to do it in elegant way. I can't just get parentComponent and use it insead of `this`, because nested component `dropdown-with-search` also have its own variables and functions. So the problem is that now it can use all `base-dropdown` methods. But it can't use parent ViewChild reference...

Comment: `this` is a **reference** to the parent, so yes you can get the parent. And again, I really don't understand your goal. But if it's related to communication between parent & child components, then this answer gives you every possible way of doing so.

Comment: My goal is to have one `base-dropdown` which have all common functionality. All inherited components, like described `dropdown-with-search` will have some extra behavior, override some functions of the `base-dropdown` if it is necessary and etc., but mostly will use methods of the `base-dropdown`. In inherited component i just can use all methods from `base-component` like `this.toggleOptions()`. But i can't do the same with template reference. I can't use in inherited `dropdown-with-child` @ViewChild reference from `base-dropdown`.

Comment: Sure i can just override `base-component` methods that uses `@ViewChild ref` from its tempalte. For example in `base-dropdown`:
`setFocus() {
  this.templateRef.nativeElement.focus()
}`

And in `dropdown-with-search` i can override it using what you described above:
`constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => ParentComponent)) private parent:ParentComponent) {
}

setFocus() {
  this.parent.templateRef.nativeElement.focus()
}`
But it will produce too match boilerplate because i have many long functions that uses `this.templateRef` in `base-dropdown`

Comment: If you want common behaviors between your components, then make a super class and/or an interface. Because Angular components aren't made for that.